# Swift: UITabbarController Overlay without covering TabBar in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, overlay

I have a UITabBarController with a custom center UIButton. I created this Button programmatically. I want a overlay(View) to appear whenever (No matter which tab you are on) you press this button. But since I am just starting getting into Swift etc. I would like to design this overlay in the main.storyboard but I can't add a View to the existing UITabBarController ViewController. I already added the addTarget to the Button so that I can call a method to show or hide the overlay.

It would be awesome if you could help me figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement like this way.

```
class MainTabbarViewController: UITabBarController {

    let viewTabbar : ViewForTabbar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.        
    viewTabbar = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewForTabbar", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as! ViewForTabbar
    viewTabbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 50)
    viewTabbar.tag = 100
    viewTabbar.delegate = self

    viewTabbar.initTabbar()
    self.view.addSubview(viewTabbar)
    }
}
```

This way you can make customized TabbarController